# Write data to a nested dictionary given a "key path" of unknown length

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object

I have a file for my app that holds (in a dictionary) general info about the app EG the settings.
The main dictionary is:

```
"info": {}
```

to write to the file, my `write` function takes two arguments. The `data` and a single `key`. For example, if I had this:

```
"info": {
    "settings": {
        "appearance": "dark"
    }
}
```

To write to `appearance` I would have first have read the entirety of `settings`, then modify `appearance` and finally write it all back to the file. Like this:

```
let new_settings = File.read("settings");
new_settings.appearance = "light";
File.write(new_settings, "settings");
//////////// data ///////// key ///
```

It's a `write` function so I shouldn't have to modify the data myself. I got the idea of being able to use a "key path". With this new "key path" all I would have to do:

```
File.write("light", "settings > appearance");
```

`settings > appearance` is saying `under settings, under appearance, write "light"`. Unfortunately I couldn't work out any better way of implementing this than just using a string and eval like so:

```
let path = "d[\"info\"]";

///"keys" is an array of the keys in the key path
///"settings > appearance" = ["settings","appearance"]

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    path = path.concat("[\"", keys[i], "\"]");
    if (!eval(path)) {
        eval(path.concat(" = {}"));
    }
    if (i === keys.length - 1) {
        //"data" is the data passed into the write function
        eval(path.concat(" = data"));
    }
}
```

I would always end up at the problem of writing to that dictionary. It's easy to read because you can loop through the keys and continue to assign to the same variable until you reach the desired one:

```
d = d[key]
```

but the moment you need to write to it:

```
d[key1][key2]//.....
```

you need to edit the main dictionary which I found hard to do when you don't know the number of keys.
Whats a better of doing this?

Comment: Treat your settings file as a JSON, this way you can convert, manipulate, and store or send through the network easily

Comment: I am converting it to a JSON object but, unless I'm missing something, that's not gonna help me because you access data in a JSON object the same way as a dictionary so I will still end up at the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a JSON object and a key-path:

```
function updateSettings(settings, keyPath, value) {
  const keys = keyPath.split('.');
  const targetKey = keys.pop();
  let current = settings;
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    current = current[keys[i]];
    if (!current) {
      throw new Error('Specified key not found. ' + keys[i]);
    }
  }
  current[targetKey] = value;
  // return settings; // optional, because it changes settings object directly
}

const settings = {
  root: 0,
  settings: {
    appearance: 'light'
  },
  some: {
    very: {
      very: {
        nested: {
          value: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

updateSettings(settings, 'settings.appearance', 'dark');
updateSettings(settings, 'root', 1024);
updateSettings(settings, 'some.very.very.nested.value', 2048);
```

the output is:

```
{
  root: 1024,
  settings: {
    appearance: 'dark'
  },
  some: {
    very: {
      very: {
        nested: {
          value: 2048
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Some libraries (e.g. [lodash _.get](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1637)) have implementation methods for this.

Comment: Ohh interesting. You see I thought if you had object `A` (say `{"test":{"test1":"1}}`), you made object B equal to `A["test"]` and then did `B["test1"] = "2"` that it wouldnt change `A`. Now that I think about it, that doesn't make sense but that was my though at the time.