# Multi level dynamic key setting?

Tags: javascript

How do you set a multi-level deep update on an object with a dynamic key in javascript? When i try a typical dynamic update, it adds another key/value pair instead of updating the correct parameter.

```js
let home = {
  street: {
    house: {
      room: {
        window: true
      }
    }
  }
}

let update = {
  key: "house.room.window",
  value: "false"
}

home.street[update.key] = update.value;
console.log(home);
```

expected:

```
home = {
    street:{
        house: {
            room: {
                window: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

instead i get:

```
home = {
    street:{
        house: {
            room: {
                window: true
            }
        }
        "house.room.window": false
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635384/write-data-to-a-nested-dictionary-given-a-key-path-of-unknown-length/64641327#64641327

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write data to a nested dictionary given a "key path" of unknown length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635384/write-data-to-a-nested-dictionary-given-a-key-path-of-unknown-length)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like below. Explanation is in comments.

```js
let home = {
  street: {
    house: {
      room: {
        window: true
      }
    }
  }
}

let update = {
  key: "house.room.window",
  value: "false"
}

// select object to get updated
let obj = home.street;
// get array of nested keys
let nestedKeys = update.key.split('.');
// get object from nested keys until last key
// used slice(0, -1) so it will iterate through all key except last one
nestedKeys.slice(0, -1).forEach(k => obj = obj[k]);

// use object with last key and update value
obj[nestedKeys[nestedKeys.length - 1]] = update.value

// log object
console.log(home);
```

Comment: i thought there would be some more elegant solution, but split does get the job done. thank you

Comment: @polar there's syntactic sugar that can improve cleanliness but the basic idea will be the same. Like `const [keys, lastKey] = update.key.split("."); keys.forEach(k => obj = obj[k]); obj[lastKey] = update.value;`

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using a library, you can try [lodash's update](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#update).

```
_.update(home, update.key, () => update.value);
```